# What is Windows constantly sending?

Tags: windows, networking, svchost

when I run perfmon /res via win+r, I notice that System and svchost are using my network to send and receive data. I use a windows 8.1 x64 computer; does anyone have some idea on what Windows is sending?

THANKS!

P.S. I know that I should not worry too much about it, but I'm just curious about it. It's just good to know more information about my computer!

Answer (score 1):

When you run Perfmon, open up the network section. Perfmon is only monitoring the apps you have running. I see DropBox, VMware, and so on. System and svchost are related activities.

You can look at the packets being sent / received with a packet sniffer (Comm View (I use this) or Wire Shark). Updates, email and web browsing are a very common source of internet traffic.

I reviewed packets with Comm View here and did not see anything out of the ordinary. My machine is Windows 10 but the same thing is true on Windows 8

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview
 Mark Russinovich (the master programmer!)

TCPView is a Windows program that will show you detailed listings

of all TCP and UDP endpoints on your system, including the local

and remote addresses and state of TCP connections.....